# How can make paging with nodejs and couchdb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, couchdb

I made page which show results from search in database. But how can I do pages not just 1000 results I want to be 100 pages with 10 results in each? I think for something like sending server the number of page? Is that correct or there is any better method?

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB views, lists and `_all_docs` URIs have `skip` and `limit` parameters to do that.

For example, here is the URI for the 9th page of 10 results each:

```
http://acme.org:5984/artists/_design/artists/_view/by-name?skip=80&limit=10
```

For further details, please look at "[Pagination Recipe](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/pagination.html#views-pagination)" in CouchDB official documentation.